# MongoDB startup "no such command" exception on Azure

Tags: azure, mongodb-.net-driver

I  received the following error when I tried to start the Azure-based MongoDB role:

> Command 'cloud' failed: no such cmd: cloud (response: { "errmsg" : "no such cmd: cloud", "bad cmd" : { "cloud" : 1, "nodes" : { "#d2" : "127.255.0.5:20003", "#d0" : "127.255.0.3:20001", "#d1" : "127.255.0.4:20002" }, "me" : "#d2" }, "ok" : 0.0 })

From the following method:

> server.RunAdminCommand(cloudCommand);

When I try to connect to the replica set through ASP.net, I get "connection refused" exception. If I instead init the replica set through the command line, I can connect to it through my asp.net application. Here is the command that I am using to init the replica set through commmand line:

> mongo 127.255.0.2:20001,127.255.0.3:20002,127.255.0.4:20003

I am stumped, I don't know how to initialize my replicaset as startup of my application. HELP!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had also seen this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/6b2ac18a-ca0f-4dc1-a63c-ffdecf8d55f5 and replace the binaries that I was using, but had no effect.

Comment: I removed the command and things started up correctly, I still don't understand what the "cloud" command is doing. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Virtual Servers on Azure, this question is now irrelevant.

Use a virtual server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you following the steps from:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+on+Azure

Especially

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Azure+Deployment

Comment: Yes, With the exception of running development storage in some cases. I also have switched up the ports and now switched them back to to 27017.